# What is the best way to configure a bucket path in react app dynamically

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bucket

I have a React JS web app that needs to build once alongside an express server that has path to the React app.

The problem is that if the server is running under a bucket, lets say example-bucket, the react app will not find the assets because it will  ask for assets from the main domain.

For example, for the following bucket: [www.example.co.il/example-bucket](http://www.example.co.il/example-bucket)

React will ask for the image from [www.example.co.il/image.jpg](http://www.example.co.il/image.jpg)
instead of [www.example.co.il/example-bucket/image.jpg](http://www.example.co.il/example-bucket/image.jpg)

This bucket path can change any time. I need a way to change the bucket path in React JS dynamically without running a build. Are there any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the React app load a JSON configuration file which contains the base URL.

Comment: but if you do build by webpack all the files go into one javascript file bundle js, and one static index.html which load the bundle

Comment: @manorLH not if the json file is in the public folder or put in the app after the app is compiled.